# Data is received at local environment but not in production in meteor js webapp

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, picker, webapp2

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/hello', async (req, res, next) => {
    let data = '';
    await req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    console.log("data : ", data)
    const xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0"?><cXML></cXML>`'
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
    res.end(xml_string);
})
```

I am using this method to get data. I am getting data as expected in the local environment. But after deployment, req.on('data') is not invoking and data is blank for the specific API. Another API is working on both production and local environments with the same code. I am send XML data in the request

Comment: This is too little code to tell. Looks like the handler of a request. What kind of request is that and how are you sending data to it?

Comment: I am sending data in XML format to this request

Comment: @ChristianFritz I have updated my question  Please check. the same API is working for /helloeveryone route

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that, but why do you have the picker tag on your question when you don't use it. Or rather, why don't you use it? Might make things a little easier.

Comment: I had same issue with picker after that I shifted to webApp

Comment: Issue is only reflected in production

Comment: @ChristianFritz On postman, it is working but if I access using SAP Ariba the data is null

Comment: well, then you'll need to figure out how SAP Ariba is sending the request. It seems to be an issue on that end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by following code.

```
Picker.route("/hello", async (params, req, res) => {
let data = ''
req.on('data', Meteor.bindEnvironment((chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
})).on('end', function() {
    console.log("data : ", data)
    const xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0"?><cXML></cXML>`'
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
    res.end(xml_string);
}
```